# NtResumeThread after NtCreateUserProcess

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I created the process through NtCreateUserProcess. This was successful and returned STATUS_SUCCESS.

This created process attempted to run through NtResumeThread in a suspended state.

But immediately the process was turned off.

In the same code, NtCreateUserProcess was replaced with CreateProcessW. NtResumeThread was used to create the same suspended process to normal process, which worked well.

How can I resume a process created with NtCreateUserProcess?

Edit: CreateProcess (Working) -> NtCreateUserProcess (Nop..) means process created with wrong code. Got it. I created process with following code.

```c
  HANDLE hProcess;
  HANDLE hThread;
  PS_CREATE_INFO procInfo;
  PS_ATTRIBUTE_LIST attrList;
  RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS10 userParams;
  RtlSecureZeroMemory(&userParams, sizeof(RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS10));
  RtlSecureZeroMemory(&attrList, sizeof(PS_ATTRIBUTE_LIST));
  RtlSecureZeroMemory(&procInfo, sizeof(PS_CREATE_INFO));

  userParams.Length = sizeof(RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS10);
  userParams.MaximumLength = sizeof(RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS10);
  attrList.TotalLength = sizeof(PS_ATTRIBUTE_LIST) - sizeof(PS_ATTRIBUTE);
  procInfo.Size = sizeof(PS_CREATE_INFO);

  userParams.Environment = (WCHAR *) data;
  userParams.EnvironmentSize = sizeof(data);
  userParams.EnvironmentVersion = 0;
  userParams.Flags = 0x01;
  userParams.ShowWindowFlags = SW_HIDE;
  userParams.ImagePathName = filename2;
  userParams.CommandLine = command;

  attrList.Attributes[0].Attribute = PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeImageName, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE);
  attrList.Attributes[0].Size = filename.Length;
  attrList.Attributes[0].Value = (ULONG_PTR) filename.Buffer;

  NTSTATUS status = INLINE_SYSCALL(NtCreateUserProcess)(&hProcess, &hThread, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED,
                                        NULL, NULL, 0, THREAD_CREATE_FLAGS_CREATE_SUSPENDED,
                                        reinterpret_cast<_RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS *>(&userParams), &procInfo, &attrList);
  if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
    printf("%x\n", status);
    return 1;
  }
```

And using following struct.

```c
typedef struct _RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS10
{
  ULONG MaximumLength;  //6c0
  ULONG Length;//6c0
  ULONG Flags;//0
  ULONG DebugFlags;//0
  HANDLE ConsoleHandle;//NULL
  ULONG ConsoleFlags;//0
  HANDLE StandardInput;//NULL
  HANDLE StandardOutput;//NULL
  HANDLE StandardError;//NULL
  CURDIR CurrentDirectory;
  UNICODE_STRING DllPath;
  UNICODE_STRING ImagePathName;
  UNICODE_STRING CommandLine;
  PWSTR Environment;
  ULONG StartingX;
  ULONG StartingY;
  ULONG CountX;
  ULONG CountY;
  ULONG CountCharsX;
  ULONG CountCharsY;
  ULONG FillAttribute;
  ULONG WindowFlags;
  ULONG ShowWindowFlags;
  UNICODE_STRING WindowTitle;
  UNICODE_STRING DesktopInfo;
  UNICODE_STRING ShellInfo;
  UNICODE_STRING RuntimeData;
  RTL_DRIVE_LETTER_CURDIR CurrentDirectories[32];
#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_LONGHORN)
  SIZE_T EnvironmentSize;
#endif
#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_WIN7)
  SIZE_T EnvironmentVersion;
#endif
} RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS10, *PRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS10;
```

I cant find any error in this process creation.

Sorry for bad english.. I'm not a native speaker so there can be some wrong grammer, graceless manner.

Comment: A bug in your code, a bug in your reasoning, or a bug in the API. We don't know until we see a [mcve]. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67792125/edit) your question to include the required information. Since you are new here, please take the time to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: wrong question. you need ask - how correct create process with call `NtCreateUserProcess`.  *But immediately the process was turned off.* - this mean that you resume process, and it begin executing. and exit, because was wrong created

Comment: I revised the writing by slightly specifying the problem.

Comment: I’m sorry I can't reproduce your problem. Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information ?